# Is there any way with which I can avoid type casting while calling method with generic parameter?

Tags: java, generics, casting

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GenericTest genericTest = new GenericTest();

    genericTest.setValue(new BigDecimal("10"),BigDecimal.class);
    genericTest.setValue(new Date(0), Date.class);

    }

    public <T> void setValue(T element, Class<T> dataType)
    {
        if(dataType == Date.class){
            checkDate((Date)element);
        }
        else if(dataType == BigDecimal.class){
            checkBigDecimal((BigDecimal)element);
        }
    }

    public void checkDate(Date localDate)
    {
        System.out.println("This is Date metho, Caller has casted T to Date");
    }

    public void checkBigDecimal(BigDecimal localBigDecimal)
    {
        System.out.println("This is BigDecimal method, Caller has casted T to BigDecimal");

    }
```

Here when the checkDate and CheckBigDecimal method is called, I did type casting to Date and BigDecimal respectively. Is it possible to avoid type casting while calling these method?

Comment: You've actually implemented a bridge method - the thing that the compiler does behind the scenes when processing type-parameters. :)

Comment: You don't need the `dataType` parameter. You can get it from `element.getClass()`. I doubt that the `setValue()` method should be generic at all: instead, you should provide all the requisite overloads.

Comment: @Tom , it is  my mistake however i did not want others to concentrate on each of the line of this program. I just put the prototype to get my answer..again thank you..

Comment: This is not production code. Ignore any other mistakes in sample program. This is just the prototype to present my question over here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make things a bit cleaner:

```
public class genericTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        genericTest genericTest = new genericTest();
        genericTest.setValue(new BigDecimal("10".toString()));
        genericTest.setValue(new Date(0));

    }

    public <T> void setValue(T element) {
        if (element instanceof Date) {
            check((Date) element);
        }

        if (element instanceof BigDecimal) {
            check((BigDecimal) element);
        }
    }

    public void check(Date localDate) {
        System.out.println("This is Date metho, Caller has casted T to Date " + localDate);
    }

    public void check(BigDecimal localBigDecimal) {
        System.out.println("This is BigDecimal method, Caller has casted T to BigDecimal: " + localBigDecimal);
    }
}
```

This however doesn't solve your problem as a cast is still needed. The problem is that you want to have method overloading applied dynamically at runtime.
Java will not do that - the compiler will attempt to resolve your code to specific (overloaded) method invocations and something like the following will fail as it cant 
figure out which (if any) `check()` to apply

```
public <T> void setValue(T element) {
    check(element);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the cast if you want the method to be generic. However, you could just overload the setValue method instead. Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    GenericTest genericTest = new GenericTest();

    genericTest.setValue(new BigDecimal("10"));
    genericTest.setValue(new Date(0));

}

public void setValue(BigDecimal element) {
    checkBigDecimal(element);
}

public void setValue(Date element) {
    checkDate(element);
}

public void checkDate(Date localDate) {
    System.out.println("This is Date metho, Caller has casted T to Date");
}

public void checkBigDecimal(BigDecimal localBigDecimal) {
    System.out.println("This is BigDecimal method, Caller has casted T to BigDecimal");
}
```

Comment: What the idea behind the question is I want to consolidate things at one place, so meaningfully, I want to create only one method that can accept both type of parameter and can call further methods..

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving the issue is to use the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), created exactly for situations where you need to create objects without having to specify the exact class for the created object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does that answer the question about avoiding type casting?

Comment: It should be detailled indeed, because it need some refactor. But we need to use overriding instead of overloading to make the polymorphism work in Java.

Comment: Using a factory is one way of avoiding direct cast and -- how the answer below shows -- clearly not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the class does not have a parameter type that can be known across method calls. You could parameterize the GenericTest class:

```
public class GenericTest<T> {
    private T value;

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

It's a good idea to have the parameter type bound class-wide since you have cross-method calls relying on the type to be the same. In other words, don't allow setValue(String) and setValue(Date) to be called on the same instance. The above code should prevent such calls.

With the above, your class won't even need the checkDate/checkBigDecimal methods (assuming they're intended for validation):

```
GenericTest<Date> dateGeneric = new GenericTest<>();
dateGeneric.setValue(new Date()); //The compiler will prevent any other type to be passed to this method
```

if the checkXYZ methods are still needed (for example, you're validating generic input), then casting can't be avoided and therefore, the use of generics is inappropriate. You could simply use an Object field and cast inside the checkXYZ methods as part of the validation.